# How to open APK files with bash? Tried to use pm install

Tags: android

https://stackoverflow.com/queavc:  could not determine enforcing mode: Permission denied Unknown class fileSystem server has no access to read file context u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 (from path /data/app/org.supertuxkart.stk-tSKbmIC7F2vR-jnUDilGOw==/base.apk, context u:r:system_server:s0) Error: Unable to open file: /data/app/org.supertuxkart.stk-tSKbmIC7F2vR-jnUDilGOw==/base.apk Consider using a file under /data/local/tmp/ Error: Can't open file: /data/app/org.supertuxkart.stk-tSKbmIC7F2vR-jnUDilGOw==/base.apk  Exception occurred while executing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Can't open file: /data/app/org.supertuxkart.stk-tSKbmIC7F2vR-jnUDilGOw==/base.apk     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:328)  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21518)     at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3889)  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)

Comment: How do I open apps with bash